# SQLBulkCopy is not inserting on table

Tags: vb.net, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using the SQLBulkCopy to load data in my table. It's works fine, but sometimes the data just don't load in my table and I don't receive any errors.

That's my code:

```
Dim dtbTabelaLoad As New DataTable("base_fat_contrato_linha_composicao")
dtbTabelaLoad.Columns.Add("fk_id_contrato")
dtbTabelaLoad.Columns.Add("access_nbr")
dtbTabelaLoad.Columns.Add("fk_id_composicao")

For Each linha As Linha In objLinhaFinal
    Dim strContrato As String = linha.ComposicaoLinha.NumeroContrato
    Dim strComposicao As String = linha.ComposicaoLinha.NumeroComposicao
    Dim strNumeroLinha As String = linha.NumeroLinha

    dtbTabelaLoad.Rows.Add(strContrato, strNumeroLinha, strComposicao)
Next

Dim load As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(strStringConexao, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default)
load.DestinationTableName = "base_fat_contrato_linha_composicao"
load.ColumnMappings.Add("fk_id_contrato", "fk_id_contrato")
load.ColumnMappings.Add("access_nbr", "access_nbr")
load.ColumnMappings.Add("fk_id_composicao", "fk_id_composicao")

load.WriteToServer(dtbTabelaLoad)
load.Close()
```

I run this code several times in my program, but sometimes the data just doesn't appear on the table.

Comment: Is objLinhaFinal the only object you are using to fill the table? When you debug, are there rows in the DataTable?

Comment: Yes Jacob, its the only one. But doing a double check on this, I discover another process that was erasing the data that was inserted by my code. So, the SQLBulkCopy is working fine, without any problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you wish, you can answer your own post with the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After see the Jacob comment, I discover another process that was erasing the data that was inserted. So, its all ok with my code (happily).

Tks.